# What will be the equivalent regular expression in python?

Tags: python, regex

**CODE IN PHP**

```
<?php
    $str = "CSIR-National Botanical Research Institute, Plant Transgenic Laboratory, U.P., India. Electronic address: i.sanyal@nbri.res.in.";
    preg_match("/([A-Z][^\s,.]+[.]?\s[(]?)*(Hospital|University|Institute|Law School|School of|Academy|College)[^,\d]*(?=,|\d)/", $str, $org_arr);
    echo $org_arr[0];   
?>
```

**OUTPUT**

> CSIR-National Botanical Research Institute

This regular expression extracts Hospital, University, Institute, School, Academy or College from a given PHP string. I tried executing the same regular expression in python but it doesn't work.

**CODE IN PYTHON**

```
import re
line = "CSIR-National Botanical Research Institute, Plant Transgenic Laboratory, U.P., India. Electronic address: i.sanyal@nbri.res.in."
match = re.search(r'/([A-Z][^\s,.]+[.]?\s[(]?)*(Hospital|University|Institute|Law School|School of|Academy|College)[^,\d]*(?=,|\d)/', line)
print(match.group(0))
```

**GIVES EROR MESSAGE**

> Traceback (most recent call last):   File "C:\Users\Ghost
>   Rider\Documents\Python\temp.py", line 4, in 
>       print(match.group(0)) AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'group'

Comment: Add some minimal examples of input and output.

Comment: *it doesn't work* is not a problem description. Please [edit] your post to include samples of what should (and should not) match, and a clear explanation of the problem you're having.

Comment: @CodeManiac done giving examples

Comment: @KenWhite Given the examples see through it if you can solve please.

Comment: The very first part of the pattern includes a slash, but there's no slash in the data that you're searching.

Comment: Just remove the PHP regex delimiters (`/`). https://rextester.com/UONH75111

Answer (score 0, accepted):

#### edit:

Nice additional detail.  You're getting an error on None type because the pattern didn't match anything; easier to show how to check than explain it...

So let's change your example a little and see if this does what you're looking for.  Note the lack of leading and trailing slashes on the pattern (see **original**, below).

```
import re
txt = "CSIR-National Botanical Research Institute, Plant Transgenic Laboratory, U.P., India. Electronic address: i.sanyal@nbri.res.in."
# note: str is the string class type, python would happily let you assign that to a string literal.
print('txt={}'.format(txt))
pattern = r'([A-Z][^\s,.]+[.]?\s[(]?)*(Hospital|University|Institute|Law School|School of|Academy|College)[^,\d]*(?=,|\d)'
m = re.search(pattern, txt)
if m:
    print('found some things, groups={}'.format(m.groups()))
else:
    print('no match')
```

results:

```
txt=CSIR-National Botanical Research Institute, Plant Transgenic Laboratory, U.P., India. Electronic address: i.sanyal@nbri.res.in.
found some things, groups=('Research ', 'Institute')
```

I think **$org_arr** part in PHP is set up in Python's **m.groups()** list.

#### original:

Maybe try it in python without the leading and trailing slashes?
Let's start by making a simple pattern work...

### PHP example

These [PHP docs](https://secure.php.net/manual/en/function.preg-match.php) show this example:

```
// The "i" after the pattern delimiter indicates a case-insensitive search
if (preg_match("/php/i", "PHP is the web scripting language of choice.")) {
    echo "A match was found.";
} else {
    echo "A match was not found.";
}
```

Since they're just searching on **php** the slashes look like pattern delimiters.

### same example in python

In Python that would be like this (not the pattern is r'php', not r'/php/').

```
import re
if re.match( r'php', 'PHP is the web scripting language of choice.', re.IGNORECASE):
    print('A match was found.')
else:
    print('A match was not found.')
```

Slightly more useful would be keeping the match object so you can use your groups...

```
import re
m = re.match( r'(php)', 'PHP is the web scripting language of choice.', re.IGNORECASE)
if m:
    print('A match was found, group(1)={}'.format(m.group(1)))
else:
    print('A match was not found.')
```